# close open dropdown when clicking to open another

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following javascript that opens drop down menus by adding the class "dropped" when links in my navigation are clicked.

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function () {
          var nextSibling = $(this).next();
              nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
 });
```

My problem is that when one dropdown is open, it does not close when you click to open another. How do I find the dropdown that is open and close it when another is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one dropdown open at any point, you may want to remove the dropped class from everything that is marked as 'dropped' before.  Here's what I would do...

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function () {
      $('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');
      var nextSibling = $(this).next();
          nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
});
```

Comment: This works to close the other open drop down, however, now it wont let me close a drop down that is already open by clicking the link. SO if I open one dropdown, and then try to close it, it wont close. But it will close if I click to a different dropdown...

Answer (score 2):

Can't you remove all the dropped classes before toggling the one that you want open:

e.g:

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function () {
          $('.dropped').removeClass('dropped');
          var nextSibling = $(this).next();
              nextSibling.addClass("dropped");  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function () {
          $(this).removeClass("dropped");
          var nextSibling = $(this).next('ul');
              nextSibling.addClass("dropped");  
 });
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GP68Q/)***